# How to compare two binary files or sets of files and displays the differences between them in Python?

Tags: python, file, batch-file, binary, compare

I have two text files and want to compare them in order to write the comparison report in the seperate file, like what we get in Batch script with the command

`fc /B file1.txt file2.txt > result.txt`.

I tried using the `filecmp.cmp('file1.txt','file2.txt')`, but this is returning me the Boolean value. 
What is the correct method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at difflib.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html

It's meant for this and `difflib.context_diff` should be what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried using this but this is not giving me output as summary.

Comment: Ok, could you edit your question, so we know what you're expecting to see? Right now, it's really hard to tell what kind of output you expect...